# IE problems on Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress

Having a huge problem with my Wordpress site displaying incorrectly only in IE.  The whole site should be centered in the middle of the page but in IE it floats left.  Also my nav options (on the sidebar once hovered over) have to much space in between them.  Lastly if you click on one of the nav options it will take you to a page containing a slide deck, that in IE is way to tall.  I've been googling this for the past few hours trying to fix it.  I know my page doesn't validate fully, but I can't find a good way to find and fix the errors since the each page is generated from wordpress and there are many different parts to each page.  I'm about to go crazy, let me know if you can help.  Thanks in advance.

http://www.buildingthemiddleclass.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your page code; you have this

```
<style type="text/css">
#headimg {
height: HEADER_IMAGE_HEIGHTpx;
width: HEADER_IMAGE_WIDTHpx;
}
#headimg h1, #headimg #desc {
display: none;
}
</style>
```

above the Doctype in header.php. Anything above the Doctype whacks IE. Fix that.

Comment: Thanks that was totally the problem.  I found there was a random piece of html code, which was just css in a style tag, in the functions file outside of the php brackets.  Don't know where that came from but deleting it took care of the problem.  Thanks again, it is much appreciated.